# Change blanks to four spaces in R

Tags: r

I am trying to make a very specific report in R. If there is a NA i need it to have four spaces else it just has the numbers. The following code changes all of the data into the four spaces.

```
mydata$num <- c(NA, NA, 5655, 5555, NA, NA)

revalue(mydata$num, c(NA="    "))
```

and

```
number <- for(i in mydata$num){
               if (is.na(mydata$num[i])) {
                  mydata$num <- "    "
           }
```

I have no more ideas of what to try. Thank you!

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mydata$num[is.na(mydata$num)]="    "
```